# Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Tags: php

I have gone through a ton of this **invalid arguments passed** messages on this forum and I am very sorry but have not found any example that helps my situation.

As you can see from the code below with the generous help of Rasclatt, I have several field names including 9 files to be uploaded to the server while the rest of the fields get submitted to the database.

When I attempt to run the code, I get, **"Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in..."** which is on line 94 - the start of the INSERT statement.

An important point to note is that not all files can be uploaded at one time during an insert.

Users can elect to upload all files, just as they can elect to just upload one file during an insert iteration.

Any idea how to resolve this?

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

 include("../Connections/Connect.php");

// this function is used to sanitize code against sql injection attack.
function ms_escape_string($data) {
        if ( !isset($data) or empty($data) ) return '';
        if ( is_numeric($data) ) return $data;

        $non_displayables = array(
            '/%0[0-8bcef]/',            // url encoded 00-08, 11, 12, 14, 15
            '/%1[0-9a-f]/',             // url encoded 16-31
            '/[\x00-\x08]/',            // 00-08
            '/\x0b/',                   // 11
            '/\x0c/',                   // 12
            '/[\x0e-\x1f]/'             // 14-31
        );
        foreach ( $non_displayables as $regex )
            $data = preg_replace( $regex, '', $data );
        $data = str_replace("'", "''", $data );
        return $data;
    }

    // You may want to add document root
    $target = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads";
    // I am filtering the files incase there are empty uploads
    // You need to have the proper file input name (item)
    $_FILES['item']['tmp_name'] =   array_filter($_FILES['item']['tmp_name']);
    $_FILES['item']['name'] =   array_filter($_FILES['item']['name']);
    $_FILES['item']['type'] =   array_filter($_FILES['item']['type']);
    $_FILES['item']['size'] =   array_filter($_FILES['item']['size']);


    foreach($_FILES['item']['name'] as $i => $value ) {
            $file_name              =   $_FILES['item']['name'][$i];
            $file_size              =   $_FILES['item']['size'][$i];
            $file_tmp               =   $_FILES['item']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $file_type              =   $_FILES['item']['type'][$i];

            $bidDate                =   ms_escape_string($_POST['txtBidDate']);
            $dueDate                =   ms_escape_string($_POST['txtDueDate']);
            $dueTime                =   ms_escape_string($_POST['txtDueTime']);
            $bidTitle               =   ms_escape_string($_POST['BidTitle']);
            $bidId                  =   ms_escape_string($_POST['BidID']);
            $desc                   =   ms_escape_string($_POST['Description']);
            $dept                   =   ms_escape_string($_POST['Department']);
            $bidContact             =   ms_escape_string($_POST['BidContact']);
            $contactEmail           =   ms_escape_string($_POST['ContactEmail']);
            $contactPhone           =   ms_escape_string($_POST['ContactPhone']);
            $numBids                =   ms_escape_string($_POST['NumofBids']);
            $awardDate              =   ms_escape_string($_POST['txtAwardDate']);
            $awardrecip1            =   ms_escape_string($_POST['AwardRecip']);
            $bidType                =   ms_escape_string($_POST['BidType']);
            $lastUpdate             =   ms_escape_string($_POST['txtLastUpdate']);
            $notes                  =   ms_escape_string($_POST['Notes']);
            $status                 =   ms_escape_string($_POST['Status']);

            $sqlArr['values'][$i]   =   "'".ms_escape_string($_FILES['item']['name'][$i])."'";
            $sqlArr['columns'][$i]  =   "Addend".$i;
            $sqlArr['columns']  =   "SignInSheet";
            $sqlArr['columns']  =   "TabSheet";
            $sqlArr['columns']  =   "BidFile";
            // At this point you are only notifying user.
            // You have no code to prevent this limitation.
            if ($file_type!="application/pdf" || $file_type!="image/gif" || $file_type!="image/jpeg")
                 $echo =    'You can only upload PDFs, JPEGs or GIF files.<br>';
            // So far, this is just for notification, you haven't
            // actually done anything about this limitation
            if($file_size >  (8 * 1024 * 1024))
                $echo='File size must be less than 8 MB';

            // Makes the folder if not already made.
            if(!is_dir($target))
                mkdir($target,0755,true);

            //Writes the files to the server
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['item']['tmp_name'][$i], $target."/".$file_name)) {
                //If all is ok
                echo "The file ". $file_name. " has been uploaded to the directory and records saved to the database";
            }
            else {

            //Gives and error if its not
            echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
            }
        }
if(isset($sqlArr['columns'])) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO bids (BidDate,DueDate,DueTime,BidTitle,BidID,Description,,'".implode("','",$sqlArr['columns'])."',Department,Xcontract,ContactEmail,ContactPhone,NumofBids,AwardDate,AwardRecip1,BidType,LastUpdate,Notes,BidStatus)
              VALUES ('$bidDate', '$dueDate','$dueTime',$bidTitle','$bidId','$desc',".implode(",",$sqlArr['values']).", '$dept','$bidContact','$contactEmail','$contactPhone','$numBids','$awardDate','$awardrecip1','$bidType','$lastUpdate','$notes',$status')" ;
    $objQuery = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
} ?>
```

Comment: Try posting the FULL ERROR MESSAGE.

Comment: @DavidSoussan, hi.

Here is the full message:

`Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in E:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test\Bitts\admin\savebids.php on line 94`

It also said successfully uploaded a couple of files I tested with even though no files in the uploads folder.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Extra comma in `BidID,Description,,` <= ? Hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

one problem:

```
 $sqlArr['columns']  =   "SignInSheet";
 $sqlArr['columns']  =   "TabSheet";
 $sqlArr['columns']  =   "BidFile";
```

is overwriting the value, not creating an array, you want:

```
 $sqlArr['columns'][]  =   "SignInSheet";
 $sqlArr['columns'][] =   "TabSheet";
 $sqlArr['columns'][]  =   "BidFile";
```

Comment: I'm also wondering about the extra comma in `BidID,Description,,` <= you think that could also have an effect on the outcome?

Comment: yeah its a bit of a mess, i just picked one problem, i would usually just comment but can't format code in comments, so i risked an 'answer'

Comment: It's worth a shot. Makes sense though.

Comment: echo "$sql" should really answer all the questions, some people don't seem to want to debug.

Comment: Yep, and yep. Debugging's part of the joy of coding ;-)

Comment: @Dagon, please bear with me good people.  I am a beginner at php, a huge leap from asp.net.

Thank you all for your assistance.

Comment: you debug asp the same way. echo the var then echo it again

Comment: @Dagon, yes of course sir. I did try to debug initially and the error I posted was still coming up.

I made the two changes recommended, one by you and one by Fred and the errors are gone.

Now, it says successfully uploaded file.

However, no file is in the uploads folder.

Comment: @Tairoc Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Also, make sure the folder you're wanting to upload to, has proper permissions to write to it. Also, that your form is POST method with a valid enctype.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, the uploads folder has permissions to write to the folder.

The form is POST:
` <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="savebids.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

I really appreciate all the help. I have been working on this since last night.

Comment: @Tairoc This line `foreach($_FILES['item']['name'] as $i => $value )` is definitely a factor. The `$value` isn't doing anything or used anywhere; it's in limbo. You'll need to modify your script accordingly, and TBH, I'm not quite sure how you need to go about it, but that is definitely an issue here. Error reporting should have defined an undefined variable and/or other error.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, thank you sir.

Also, I noticed when I debugged the code that the code is not producing the correct results.

For instance, Addend on the form is Addend1 through Addend6 plus those additional three, SignInSheet, TabSheet and BidFile but on the database, I see Addend0 on the low end and Addend8.

What is TBH?

Comment: @Tairoc "TBH", is short form for "To Be Honest". I won't be able to help out any futher; I'm going to bed. I hope you resolve it, *cheers*